# Django larger videos are not rendering

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a django app that is serving video files that were uploaded by a user and saved.  The videos that are 1 second and 2 seconds work and embed just fine, but the videos that are 24-27 seconds don't render and produce the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 217, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[10/Aug/2014 09:17:41] "GET /media/mbaron/video3.MOV HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49384)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I'm rendering a video with the following code in my template:

```
<video controls="controls" width="800" height="600" name="Video Name" src="/media/{{  profile.video2 }}"></video>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it work without the DEBUG?:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4444

Comment: You mean DEBUG = False in settings.py?  I changed that setting to False and tested again, and no luck (it just said a 500.html template didn't exist).  I was also looking at that link you attached and didn't see a specific solution to the issue! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes the link I provided is still an issue, yet thats an issue appearing when you run with DEBUG=False, sorry can't help much on this one.